# Returning a `tuple[str, str]` from `str.split(s, maxsplit=1)`

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have this function:

```py
__version__: str | None = ...

def get_version_parts() -> tuple[str, str] | None:
    if __version__ is None:
        return None
    return tuple(__version__.split('+', maxsplit=1))
```

Unsurprisingly, Mypy does not realize that the returned value here is indeed `tuple[str, str]`, instead thinking that it is a `tuple[str, ...]`.

Do I have to use `typing.cast` here, or is there some other way to work around this problem?

Comment: It can return a single part if there’s no `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I forgot about the case when the string does *not* contain a `+`. Then only *one* value is produced, not two. Credit to "Ry-" in the comments for pointing this out.

I am leaving this post and answer up because I think the "unpack, then return" idiom might be useful to other people.

---

One workaround that makes sense for small tuples, but incurs a (tiny) runtime cost, is to explicitly unpack the tuple:

```py
def get_version_parts() -> tuple[str, str] | None:
    if __version__ is None:
        return None
    calendar, revision = __version__.split('+', maxsplit=1)
    return calendar, revision
```

I tried a few other combinations along the lines of `assert len(result) == 2`, but this is the only one that worked.

Mypy apparently is not able to narrow the type of a `tuple[str, ...]` to a `tuple[str, str]` even when its length is statically-known.

Perhaps this would be an interesting feature request, but I am content with the unpacking solution for now.

Comment: It's interesting that it's able to do it for the tuple assignment, but it can't propagate it when the split call is returned directly.

Comment: The problem is that the fact that `split` will return a 2-tuple is not something you can encode in the static type of `split`, even if the value of the `maxsplit` argument is hard-coded. This is a use-case for `cast`, where you can assert facts that the type checker cannot infer.

Comment: I think because unpacking is built into the language, the type checker can special-case the fact that if `calendar, revision = ...` actually performs an assignment, then the tuple being assigned must have exactly two elements.

Comment: @chepner it's because `calendar, revision = ` is just assignment to two separate variables, it's not creating a tuple. So when you construct a tuple from those two variables, you get a tuple of statically-known size.

Comment: Right; the assignment behaves much like an `assert`. If the assignment fails because the right-hand side doesn't produce a `tuple[str, str]`, then the function won't return at all.

Comment: One thing here: you really don't need `tuple(...)` here, just unpack `split` return. It should reduce the runtime cost.

Comment: @SUTerliakov good correction, I think that was just left over from a previous version of this code when I was messing around. I will edit accordingly, it's better style not to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give my two cents: The length of the tuple is **not** statically known. It is determined at **runtime** by the output of the `str.split` method.

Of course, nothing about the signature of `str.split` tells the type checker the length of the list it returns because that is not even possible to annotate. (The generic `list` accepts exactly one type argument.)

Even *if* `str.split` returned a tuple, which can be annotated to indicate its length, it would still be impossible to cover the literal infinity of cases. Here is an example of how that could be done *theoretically* with a custom `split_str` function:

```py
from typing import Literal, overload

@overload
def split_str(s: str, maxsplit: Literal[-1]) -> tuple[str, ...]:
    ...

@overload
def split_str(s: str, maxsplit: Literal[0]) -> tuple[str]:
    ...

@overload
def split_str(s: str, maxsplit: Literal[1]) -> tuple[str, str]:
    ...

@overload
def split_str(s: str, maxsplit: Literal[2]) -> tuple[str, str, str]:
    ...

def split_str(s: str, maxsplit: int = -1) -> tuple[str, ...]:
    return tuple(s.split(maxsplit=maxsplit))

def foo() -> tuple[str, str, str]:
    return split_str("a b c", maxsplit=2)
```

The problem is of course that there is no variant for any `maxsplit` value other than `-1`, `0`, `1` and `2`. Any other call will cause `mypy` to complain.

---

All `mypy` sees with `tuple("a b c".split(maxsplit=1))` is `tuple` receiving a `list[str]` (which corresponds to the `Iterable[T]` is expects) and thus the `tuple[str, ...]` is what comes out. An `Iterable` does not even *have* a length in general, so there is no way to annnotate the `tuple` conversion any other way either.

Though I admit it would be nice to relate the `tuple.__len__` assertion to the type argument of `tuple` somehow. I imagine this opens a whole other can of worms though.

And while that one unpacking-assignment may be passed by `mypy`, it still does make it update what it thinks about the specification of the unpacked tuple:

```py
t = tuple([1, 2])
x, y = t  # no complaints
reveal_type(t)  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[builtins.int, ...]"
```

Who knows, maybe this will change in the future.

Comment: I think some kind of dependent-type support would be required to tie the value of `maxsplit` to the return type of `split`, but even that would require `maxsplit` to be an `int`, not an `Optional[int]`.

Comment: @chepner Exactly. If there were some annotation construct allowing `tuple[LEN, TYPE]`  as an option **and** some kind of dependent type for `LEN` to be whatever `Literal` integer is passed for `maxsplit`, that _could_ conceivably work, but I highly doubt that we'll see something like that any time soon.